# How to make instagram chat screen(UI) for left swipe to see time in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, user-interface, uicollectionviewlayout

[image]

We try to make swipe to left but we failed to implement like Instagram message UI in iOS Native App. Please suggest me what can I do and how to implement this.

Comment: What you have done so far

Comment: I didn't done anything because I have no idea about his how and where to start this design.

Comment: Anyone have an Android alternative to achieving this? Also is there a name for this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sharing the code with you:

Instead of using `viewForHeaderInSection` use `cellForRowAt` to create header
Also When making `Xib` for header cell please keep in mind that you have to keep the label in center of the view.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var headersIndex = [IndexPath]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "cell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "HeaderTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "HeaderTableViewCell")
}
}
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 5
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 5 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderTableViewCell") as! HeaderTableViewCell
        cell.centerLabel.text = "sanjay"
        cell.centerLabel.center.x = view.center.x
        if !headersIndex.contains(indexPath) {
            headersIndex.append(indexPath)
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! cell
        cell.leftLabel.text = "Message \(indexPath.row)"
        cell.rightLabel.text = indexPath.row.description
        return cell
    }
}
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    for i in headersIndex {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: i) {
            if tableView.visibleCells.contains(cell) {
                let header = cell as! HeaderTableViewCell
                header.centerLabel.center.x = view.center.x + scrollView.contentOffset.x
            }
        }

    }

}
}
```

[image]

Comment: please uncheck the paging enabled in attribute inspector for tableView which I said to do in previous answer

Comment: please share with me your demo project.

Comment: @sanjaykmwt can you tell me how to do it in flutter?

Comment: @ParthBhanderi no I don't know flutter.

Comment: @ParthBhanderi did you manage to achieve this in flutter so far?

Comment: @hio No, My project UI/UX team change the design after this issue.

Comment: i figure it out here, ik its late but lmk if you want it to know :)

Answer (score 1):

you just need to make some modification in the tableViewConstraints.
make the table view trailing constraint in negative value which will let the table view move out of the superview, I have used -50 as shown in the image

[image]

now when you will make the Xib of the tableViewCell also include the right side label in the same Xib.

also goto storyboard and select your tableView and in the attribute inspector in scrollView section enable all three options as shown in the below image:

[image]

now try and feel free to ask if you have any doubts.

And this is how it will look:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for give me a suggestion but have 1 more question I will do this but it will scroll the whole tableView but I need stand the date in the center of the screen please check in Instagram. I think you get more idea what I need.

Comment: I am working on this problem, If you find any solution please post it here as a answer

Comment: hello bro resolved your issue posting another answer please check

Comment: @sanjaykmwt This is working perfectly but by mistake, I did the right swipe, and after that table view is bouncing into the whole screen on swipe. Any solution on that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution sharing early without completing it, will update it after done with chat.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
 runApp( MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
 MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
   final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController(keepScrollOffset: 
   true, initialScrollOffset: 0.0);

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter chat insta'),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onHorizontalDragUpdate:(offset){
          _scrollController.animateTo(offset.localPosition.distance
              , duration: const Duration(microseconds: 800), curve: Curves.easeInBack);
        },
        onHorizontalDragEnd: (dragState){
          _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.initialScrollOffset, duration: const Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.ease);
        },
        child: ListView(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          controller: _scrollController,
          children: [
            DataTable(
              columns: const [
                DataColumn(
                    label: Text('ID',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                DataColumn(
                    label: Text('Name',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                DataColumn(
                    label: Text('Profession',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                DataColumn(
                    label: Text('',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                DataColumn(
                    label: Text('TIme',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              ],
              rows: const [
                DataRow(cells: [
                  DataCell(Text('1')),
                  DataCell(Text('Stephen')),
                  DataCell(Text('Actor')),
                  DataCell(Text('')),
                  DataCell(Text('1:30 Pm')),
                ]),
                DataRow(cells: [
                  DataCell(Text('5')),
                  DataCell(Text('John')),
                  DataCell(Text('Student')),
                  DataCell(Text('')),
                  DataCell(Text('1:30 Pm')),
                ]),
                DataRow(cells: [
                  DataCell(Text('10')),
                  DataCell(Text('Harry')),
                  DataCell(Text('Leader')),
                  DataCell(Text('')),
                  DataCell(Text('1:30 Pm')),
                ]),
                DataRow(cells: [
                  DataCell(Text('15')),
                  DataCell(Text('Peter')),
                  DataCell(Text('Scientist')),
                  DataCell(Text('')),
                  DataCell(Text('1:30 Pm')),
                ]),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      )),
   );
   }
 }
```

[image]